# Insert values from form to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What did I do wrong? My code doesn't work

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $fecha = ($_POST['fecha']);//date
    $hora_in = ($_POST['hora_incial']); //time
    $hora_fin = ($_POST['hora_final']);//time
    $comentarios =($_POST['comentarios']);//text

    //inserting data order
    $order = "INSERT INTO control ('Fecha','Hora_incial','Hora_final','Comentarios') VALUES('".$fecha."','".$hora_in."','".$hora_fin."','".$comentarios."')";

    //declare in the order variable
    $result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
    if($result){
        echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
    } else{
        echo("<br>Input data is fail"); 
    }
}
```

It shows me fail always. The connection is ok, but I can't insert the data

Thanks for you help !! :)

Comment: What does mysql_error() say? Have you verified the query is correct?  Are all of the values what you expect?

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities... enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around your column names and replace with backticks.

```
(`Fecha`,`Hora_incial`,`Hora_final`,`Comentarios`)
```

Quotes cannot be used for tables or column names

Line rewrite: (EDIT-added `$con`)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$fecha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['fecha']);//date
$hora_in = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['hora_incial']); //time
$hora_fin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['hora_final']);//time
$comentarios = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['comentarios']);//text

$order = "INSERT INTO control (`Fecha`,`Hora_incial`,`Hora_final`,`Comentarios`) VALUES('$fecha','$hora_in','$hora_fin','$comentarios')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$order);

if(! $result )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

else { echo "Success"; }

}
```

I also encourage you to switch to using [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Plus [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is also an option.

Do read the following:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Comment: Do your columns exist and that your form elements are properly named? I.e.: `<input type="text" name="fecha">` etc.? @Deimos and I assume you are connected to DB?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given  this message i have now,  yes is connect to DB, with mysqli, and i change to $result = mysqli_query($order); is this ok?
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "jazmin";

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

Comment: Ok, I think I know. I will edit my answer. @Deimos give me a minute or so.

Comment: See my edit, or use `$result = mysql_query($con, $order);` @Deimos

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' something is wrong with linea i think

Comment: Wait, I made a mistake. I am too used to using `mysqli_` and placing connection first. I edited it again. @Deimos

Comment: Hold on. Your DB connection is `mysqli_` it's confusing me. Give me a few more minutes, I'll fix it. @Deimos

Comment: You're welcome. Ok, try it now and reload my answer. You were mixing your query with `mysql_*` functions with a `mysqli_*` connection method, they don't mix together. @Deimos

Comment: You're very much welcome. I'm always glad to hear when something gets solved. Thank you and have a nice day/evening as well, cheers! @Deimos

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
$order = "INSERT INTO control 
        ."(Fecha,Hora_incial,Hora_final,Comentarios)" 
        ." VALUES"
        ."('$fecha','$hora_in','$hora_fin','$comentarios')";
```

i dont understand why you use dots in ".$variable."

whe you have a problem, try first to echo your query, like

```
echo $order;
```

and past it in your phpmyadmin (if you have one).